# What is the probability of rain over a number of days, given the probability of rain for each day?

Tags: probability

Assume that meteoroligists can predict the *probability* of rain accurately.
If they predict the next seven days all have a 20% chance of rain, what is the probability of it raining at least one of those days?   Two days?  What's the general formula?

Comment: Also, what if the probabilities are different for each day, such as { .1, 0, .25, .7, 0, .1, 0 } ?

Comment: The probability of at least one day having rain is simple if you first compute the probability of getting no rain on every day.

Comment: so.. chance of no rain on one day is 1- 20% = 80%. chance of no rain ever day is 80% ^ 7 = .209.  So the answer is 1 - .209 = .79 = 79% chance of rain during the week.

Comment: Yes, exactly right on the at least one day part.

Comment: *Hint:* The number of successful outcomes of series of trials each with an identical chance of success has a **Binomial Distribution**.

Comment: For your example of having different probabilities on each day, you might want to use a program or excel in my opinion.  Not quite as straightforward.

Comment: You need independence to use the binomial distribution.  If the weather forecasters were sure it would rain for exactly one or two days but did not know which days, then the probabilities would be $1$ and $0.4$.  If the weather forecasters were sure it would rain all week or be dry all week, then the probabilities would be $0.2$ and $0.2$.

Answer (score 4):

In this example, the probability of it raining $n$ days is the number of ways you can pick those $n$ days out of $7$, multiplied by $.20$ for each of those $7$ days, multiplied by $.8$ for each of the days it doesn't rain.

$$P(\text{rains on n days}) = {7\choose n} (.20)^n (.80)^{7-n}$$

Comment: so, n=1.  7choose1 = 7.    --->  7*(.2^1)*(.8^6) = .367 or 37%

Comment: Correct.  Here is some info to check your work.  You can expand the table of values.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial+distribution%2C+number+of+trials%3D7%2C+probability+of+success%3D.2

Comment: You have assumed independence of rainy days, which is not stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a binomial distribution. For that, we have the formula
$p(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}(p^x)(q^{n-x})$
For our scenario, we have $p=0.2$, and
$q=1-p=1-0.2=0.9$

If we want to find the probability of rain for two days out of seven, we set
$x=2,n=7$.

We then get
$p(X=2)= \binom{7}{2}(0.2^2)(0.8^5)
        =21(0.04)(0.32768)=0.2752512$

Comment: Use LaTeX please. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020